# no fuel to carburater on new Kohler CH668 engine

Tags: fuel-system

I installed brand new Kohler CH 668 in my mower. Motor does not start, fuel comes to carburator, but no fuel sprays into it. When pouring small amount of gas into carburator, it will run for a few seconds. tried to hold hand over carburator and after pouring gas and trottle at half speed with choke half open it will run on low speed for a minute or two. I know that it has solenoid shut-off, but then why would it run as described above?? I am lost?

Comment: Take a 1/2 inch wrench and tap gently on the carb, see if you can unstick the float.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be a solenoid shut-off or it could be that the float height is set incorrectly or the needle valve is jammed.